# How to get image body in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to get an extension (or HTTP headers received) and base64-encoded (seems like JS doesn't have a built-in encoding function, so "binary" would be ok too) body of an image on a page. How can I do it?

This probably seems to be a weird action, but I really need to do it this way: I have a browser object and want to get such data from the last loaded page. The driver supports executing JS in the context of the current page so I think it is probably the best solution.

**Update:**

See, I already have a page with all the images on it and I don't want to request any of them again. I want to get the data string (like `"GIF89a��÷–�Òíÿ…™ë�•æ‡ší~’âÔîÿ}‘à‡�¤ÇãÿÓÕäŠœî…˜ë`) of a certain image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript) is a duplicate, and has been answered, albeit with a lot of discussion.

Another idea: If you can influence the source document, you could embed all images as [inline images](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/). The "src" attribute *should* then contain the whole base64 string, however I have never tried this out.

Answer (score 1):

Just use XmlHttpRequest to fetch the image? http://codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=141041

Do we mean "formatting the received data and display an hex dump"?  You can probably consult a previous post related to this topic: [Is there a way to read binary data in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327685/is-there-a-way-to-read-binary-data-into-javascript)

Comment: If the image is cacheable (policy returned through the HTTP headers) then the browser might fetch it from its cache.