# How to parse a binary file using Javascript and Ajax

Tags: ajax, binary

I am trying to use JQuery to pull a binary file from a webserver, parse it in Javascript and display the contents. I can get the file ok and parse some of the file correctly. How ever I am running into trouble with one byte not coming out as expected.

I am parsing the file a byte at a time, it is correct until I get to the hex value B6 where I am getting FD instead of B6.

Function to read a byte

```
data.charCodeAt(0) & 0xff;
```

File As Hex:
02 00 00 00 55 4C 04 00 B6 00 00 00

The format I want to parse the file out into.

- short: 0002
- short: 0000
- string: UL
- short: 0004
- long: 0000B6

Any hints as to why the last value is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327685/is-there-a-way-to-read-binary-data-into-javascript).  The short answer is that you can't easily handle binary data in javascript, and charCodeAt deals with Unicode characters so it's certainly not suitable for binary manipulation.