# AJAX PDF download with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, download, binary-data

#### This is what I want to do:

I want to send an HTTP request to a server, potentially returning a PDF file. But the server may also just return an error code (PDF file unavailable, PDF file invalid, PDF system down, etc). When I get the PDF, I would like to open the PDF and refresh the page that loaded the PDF, because the PDF is then marked as "read". When I get an error code (or timeout), I would like to redirect the page to an error screen. Downloading Google Chrome works in a similar manner:

http://www.google.com/chrome/eula.html?hl=en&platform=win

#### This is what I don't want do:

For performance reasons, I don't want to issue two requests as suggested in this question here:

[Download and open pdf file using Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999607/download-and-open-pdf-file-using-ajax)

Two requests can mean:

1. Make a request for the PDF and return a code to indicate whether the PDF is available or not. If unavailable, immediately display an error page
2. If it is available, open a window and request the PDF again in that window, and display it.

That's expensive because the PDF's have to be accessed via remote systems. I don't want to access the PDF resource twice. Another solution involving two requests:

1. Make a request for the PDF and retrieve an error code or a temporary URL where the PDF is cached. On error, immediately display an error page
2. If the PDF is available, open a window in which the cached PDF is displayed.

This will require for quite a large cache for the PDF's

#### This might be an interesting lead:

I found this question here giving me some information about how I could download the binary data and make it available in JavaScript as binary data:

[Is there a way to read binary data in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327685/is-there-a-way-to-read-binary-data-into-javascript)

Maybe that's a nice lead, but of course it won't solve my problem yet, as I want to use the browser's default editor to open the file, just as if I had requested the file from a normal URL.

#### So the question is:

Can I download binary data and open them like a regular document from JavaScript? If not, I'll cache the document in some managed memory container in Weblogic and just hope that this won't kill our system. Please only respond:

- If you *know for sure* it cannot be done (some links explaining why would be nice)
- If you *know* how to do it
- If you have a different solution doing roughly what I want to do (not issuing two requests)

Comment: You lost me at "fetching PDF's two times"... why would you ever have to fetch it twice?

Comment: Hmm, true, that might not make sense outside of my head. I'll rephrase that section

Comment: You can display pdf files with javascript. The most popular library is [pdf.js](https://github.com/andreasgal/pdf.js), [demo](http://people.mozilla.org/~gal/test.html). Also you can fetch raw html via ajax request (or part of code on the page) and generate pdf with [jspdf](http://code.google.com/p/jspdf/) as binary data via data:uri - [demos](http://snapshotmedia.co.uk/blog/jspdf)

Comment: @atma: Amazing libraries! They might not be useful for me, but nice to see...

Comment: Just interesting. If you want to use the browser's default viewer and only one request, why you can not encode on the server side pdf file (e.g. `base64_encode` in php) and make response like a `{success: true, message: "all ok", code: xx, data: encoded_bin_data}`. Then `if (resp.success) document.location.href = 'data:application/pdf;base64,'+encoded_bin_data; else show_error_page(resp.code)`?

Comment: @atma: I've tried those `data:` urls (jspdf demos). They don't seem to be supported by Firefox or IE very well. I need full compatibility, even with older IE versions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The implemented "old-school" solution works like this:

1. The JavaScript client sends an AJAX request to the server to "prepare" a PDF document
2. The server responds with any of these three messages:

   - a) Document available at URL http://www.example.com/doc.pdf
   - b) Document unavailable
   - c) Document being "prepared" (i.e. client has to wait)
3. The JavaScript client then reacts as such:

   - a) Open the returned URL in a new window, refresh the current window after 5 seconds
   - b) The current window is redirected to an error screen
   - c) The current window stays unchanged and AJAX polling is implemented to repeat step 2

Comment: This only allows you to inform the user when their file is prepared, right? You won't know when the file has actually been downloaded successfully?

Comment: @crush: Why not? I mean, the download is a "classic" download of a PDF at a given URL. Browsers tend to indicate successful downloads...