# How to use unit8array in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Accorting to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/327688/669677) answer's comment, I would like to use Unit8Array to achieve the same thing:

```
var bin = parseInt('1000', 2); //=8
```

I mean:

inputs are:

```
length = 4
digits = [1,0,0,0]
```

and after some TypedArray magic the output will be:

```
8
```

Lets see a concrete example with (2 bits length):

```
counts = {};
var a = [[0,1],[0,0],[0,1],[0,0],[0,0],[1,1]]; 
for(var i in a){
  var id = parseInt(a[i].join(''), 2);
  if(!++counts[id])counts[id] = 1;
}
console.log(counts); //{0: 3, 1: 2, 3: 1}
```

[my notes are here.](http://jsbin.com/UZiGuxE/1/edit)

Comment: Why would a TypedArray be useful here?

Comment: it is (must be) faster

Comment: Can you please step back a bit and explain what you want to do? Maybe `Uint8Array` is not really part of the best solution here. You seem to want to use an array (a sequence of 8-bit unsigned integers) to convert a binary representation to a single 8-bit uint (where does the array come into play?). Working with single bits is usually done efficiently with bitshifting (`<<` and `>>`).

Comment: OK I extend my question.

Comment: it still makes no sense.  The only feature a typed array gives you that may be of use is the ability to "cast" an array of other types (e.g. UInt32) into a byte array.  None of that helps with your ASCII binary conversion - a raw "binary" array is not remotely the same thing as a string of binary digits, it's unfortunate that some people use the word "binary" to differentiate "raw" data from "human readable" data.

Comment: @Alnitak So there is no basic way to cast typed array to int?

Comment: Sure there is, but without knowing what problem _exactly_ you're trying to solve (it appears to be something to do with converting _ASCII_ base 2 into a number) I don't see how it's going to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want more speed, handle allready the ids as integers, not array, and have bit changed with & and | operations :

```
 counts = {};
 var a = [1,0,1,0,0,3]; 
 for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++ ){
    var c = counts[a[i]] || 0 ;
    counts[a[i]]= c+1 ;
 }
 console.log(counts); // { 0: 3,  1: 2, 3: 1 }
```

to set the k-th bit :

```
id |=  1 << k;
```

to clear the k-th bit :

```
id &= !(1 << k);
```

to swap the k-th bit :

```
id ^= (1 << k);
```

to read the k-th bit :

```
bitK = (id >> k ) & 1;
```

So you might write small functions to do those operations, with a 99% chance they will get
inlined by the javascript engine, it will be much faster than array handling + parseInt.
You might even write this code directly. Maybe in some case you will be able to
cache 1 << k, but anyway, shift instructions have a very little cost.

Another advantage is that you can handle several tests in a single instruction, 
for instance :

```
var setRequiredMask   = ( 1<<3 |  1<<5 ) ;   // to test if bits 3 and 5 set
var clearRequiredMask = ( 1<<2 | 1 <<4 ) ;   // to test if bit 2 and 4 cleared
var someRequiredMask  = ( 1<<0 | 1 <<6 ) ;   // to test if either bit 0 or bit 6 to be set

var satisfyConditions = ((id & setRequiredMask) == setRequiredMask) && 
                         ((id & !clearRequiredMask) ==0 ) &&
                            (id & someRequiredMask) ;
```

Here we trade 7 access to memory to quite the same number of boolean operations.
If this test is used in a loop to filter an array, the speed gain is huge.

In the same way you can set / clear / swap  several bits in a single instruction, test if one condition set is included in the other, test if they are orthogonal, .... all in a very fast way.

Only limit is that you can handle no more than 32 possibilities with this method.

Then you can store the ids in a typed a typed array, depending on the max number
of possibilities, use only a Int8Array or a Int32Array, but i am not sure the gain
in performance will be that interesting compared to [].

Syntax :

```
var arr = new Int8Array( _length_ );
```

or

```
var arr = new Int32Array( _length_ );
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get this **[`parseInt(string, radix)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)**

> **radix** An integer that represents the radix of the above mentioned
>   string.

Not sure, is like this somewhat you expect

```
var x = new Uint8Array([1,0,0,0]);
var a = x[0].toString()+x[1].toString()+x[2].toString()+x[3].toString();
console.log(parseInt(a, 2));
console.log(a.length);
```

Comment: May I know the reason for the conversion?

Comment: the returned integer will be an 'id' for possibility matrix, e.g.: possibility matrix is:[sun is shining,I'm happy], id 0 (0,0) means: sun is not shining and I'm unhappy, id 1 (0,1) means: sun is not shining and I'm happy, etc... until id=3

Comment: i don't want a conversion to string, only to int

Answer (score 0):

Is this useful?

```
var a = 1 << 3; // shift the bits of 1 (0001) 3 places: 1000
if (a == 8) {
    // this block will execute
}
```

Another example:

```
var i,
    result = 0,
    len = 4,
    bits = [1, 0, 0, 0];

for (i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    result = (result << 1) + bits[i];
}

alert(result);
```

Keep in mind, `parseInt` is probably faster than this.