# Javascript Is it OK to set boolean value in array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, boolean

Javascript question.

As title says, is it OK manner to set boolean values(`true` or `false`) to an array and check if either one of those exits in array afterwards?

Let's say I have function that returns either `true` or `false`.

*Sample code:(using jQuery)*

```
var abort = [];//make an empty array

function someFunc() {
    var returnVal = false;

    if( some condition ) {
        returnVal = true;
        return returnVal;
    }

    return returnVal;
}

someElement.each(function() {
    abort.push( someFunc() );    //push true or false in array
});
//abort array will look eventually something like...
//[true, false, true, false, false, true, ...]

//check if `true` exists in array jQuery approach
var stop = ( $.inArray(true, abort) > -1) ? true : false ;

if( stop ) {
    console.log('TRUE FOUND AT LEAST ONE IN ARRAY!');
}
```

This seems working OK.
But I was just wondering if this is the right way...

Comment: Why do you even think it wouldn't be OK to add booleans to an array? You can put any value into an array!

Comment: Perfectly ok. I'd shorten it to `function somefunc() { return(some condition)}`, though. And even more general: Are you using the different `Boolean`s in `abort` later on? If not, a single global is sufficient: `someElement.each(function() {if (! stop) {stop = someFunc()};});` in this case replaces the `$.inArray` stuff as well.

Comment: how many booleans do you need ? because a single integer might be handy to use and have great performances if you are using less than 31 booleans. You might have a look at my answer on that question for instance : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547164/how-to-use-unit8array-in-javascript/18548027#18548027

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to invoke all the functions, if any of the functions return `true`, you can use native [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method like this

```
if (someElement.some(function(currentObject) {
    return <a bool value>;
}))) {
    console.log("Value exists");
} else {
    console.loe("Value doesn't exist");
}
```

For example,

```
var someArray = [1,5,6,8,3,8];

if(someArray.some(function(currentObject) {
    return currentObject === 3;
})) {
    console.log("3 exists in the array");
} else {
    console.log("3 does not exist in the array");
}
```

would print

```
3 exists in the array
```

If you want to execute all the functions irrespective of all the results but if you want to know if atleast one of them returned `true`, then you can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), like this

```
var someArray = [1,5,6,8,4,8];

function printer(currentObject) {
    console.log(currentObject);
    return currentObject === 3;
}

if(someArray.reduce(function(result, currentObject) {
    return result || printer(currentObject);
}, false)) {
    console.log("3 exists in the array");
} else {
    console.log("3 does not exist in the array");
}
```

**Output**

```
1
5
6
8
4
8
3 does not exist in the array
```